# Can't get horizontal scrollbar to appear for wide picture

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to display a picture in react that is very long and I want a horizontal scrollbar.   However, I can't figure out how to do this.  I have tried the MUI Card, Box component="img", and <img src= and none display a scroll.  Google only lists scrollbars for slide shows, etc. which is n/a.  I have tried setting the width and height (also maxWidth/maxHeight) but that doesn't trigger the scrollbar.  Here are some examples of what I have tried.

The Image() is a function that returns the required path to image.

```
    <img src={Image (props.image)} alt={props.alt} width={300} height={194} overflow-y='scroll'/>

    <Box
        component="img"
        sx={{
            height: 194,
            width: 1280,
            maxWidth: 1280,
            maxHeight: 194,
        }}
        alt={props.alt}
        src={Image (props.image)}
    />

/**
 * Verify the image exists and return the path.
 *
 * @param name The image name.
 * @returns null if not found or the 'module.exports' value of the path to the image
 */
const Image = (name) => {
    try {
        // Import image on demand, ex. "/rdt/static/media/barOrientation.e672f57a86d61511436d.png"
        const image = require("../../../assets/" + name);

        // If the image doesn't exist. return null
        if (!image) return null;
        return image;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(`Image with name " + name + " does not exist`);
        return null;
    }
};

return (
    <Card sx={{ maxWidth: 1280 }}>
        <CardHeader
            title={props.title}
        />
        <CardMedia
            style={{ height: 150, paddingTop: "2%" }}
            component="img"
            height="194"
            image={Image (props.image)}
            alt={props.alt}
        />
    </Card>
    );
```

So what do I need to add to get a Y scrollbar?
I

Answer (score 0):

After lots of googling and experimenting, I finally got the Card to have a scrollbar by wrapping DisplayImage class with a  block and putting the scrolling attributes on that.

I am using MUI Card/CardMedia as follows:

```
    function DisplayImage(props) {

    /**
     * Verify the image exists and return the path.
     *
     * @param name The image name.
     * @returns null if not found or the 'module.exports' value of the path to the image
     */
    const Image = (name) => {
        try {
            // Import image on demand, ex. "/rdt/static/media/barOrientation.e672f57a86d61511436d.png"
            const image = require("../../../assets/" + name);

            // If the image doesn't exist. return null
            if (!image) return null;
            return image;
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(`Image with name " + name + " does not exist`);
            return null;
        }
    };

    return (
        <Card sx={{ maxWidth: 1360, minWidth: 1360, }}>
            <CardHeader
                title={props.title}
            />
            <CardMedia
                style={{ height: 150, }}
                component="img"
                height="194"
                image={Image (props.image)}
                alt={props.alt}
            />
        </Card>
    );
}

export default DisplayImage;
```

And in the parent class using DisplayImage:

```
        <div style={{ height: 230, overflow: "auto" }}>
            <DisplayImage
                title="Orientation Button Section (Example)"
                image={lcOrgc ? "panBarOrientationGC.png" : "panBarOrientationLC.png"}
                alt="Location of Orientation Section"
            />
        </div>
```

By wrapping the DisplayImage and setting the **height and overflow** and setting **maxWidth**: 1360, **minWidth**: 1360, on the Card, the scroll appeared.  As for the CardMedia Style height, this is for setting the image height in the Card and has nothing to do with the scrollbar stuff.